# Matching lists in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am building a system that contains consultant profiles. In this system, each consultant can choose which certifications he or she has. Right now I am expanding the system to contain titles when a consultant has a certain set of certifications. The interesting tables is:

```
Person(stores ID, Firstname etc. of a person)

Certification(stores ID, Name of a certification)

PersonCertification(stores PersonID and CertificationID as a linking table (name?) )

Title(stores the title: ID, Shortname and Fullname)

TitleCertifications(stores which certifications is needed for a title)
```

As an example, say we have a title with ID 1 called MCSA. The certifications required for this title is certifications with ID 1 and 2. TitleCertifications-table could look like this:

```
TitleID | CertificationID
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

If a consultant has both certification with ID 1 and 2, he or she would be granted the title MCSA with ID 1. If the consultant does not have any of the certifications, he does not earn this title.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to check if the user has all the requred certifications that is defined in the TitleCertifications-table. i have started with this, but it lacks any check against if the person has all certifications that is needed.

```
SELECT t.Fullname
FROM Title t
JOIN TitleCertifications tc ON t.ID = tc.TitleID
JOIN PersonCertification pc ON tc.CertificationID = pc.CertificationID
```

The result of the query above will yield the titlename for each rows with a match on certification, as an example it will yield two rows if a user has two of the three required certifications to gain a title.

Does anyone know how to write a query that will match the required certifications and only give an answer if the user has all the required certifications for a title?

I am using a SQL Server 2012 using T-SQL (in Azure if that matters).

Sorry for writing kinds of fuzzy, I am not sure about all the terms in English.

Comment: Do you want the query that will return a particular certification or all that user has?

Comment: The goal of the query is to return eventual titles, if any. Seems I have some answers to lead the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
;with pc as (
    select p.personid, tc.titleid, count(*) as cnt_pc
    from person p
    inner join personcertification pc on p.personid = pc.personid
    inner join titlecertifications tc on pc.certificationid = tc.certificationid
    group by p.personid, tc.titleid
),
tc as (
    select t.titleid, count(*) as cnt_tc
    from title t
    inner join titlecertifications tc on t.titleid = tc.titleid
    group by t.titleid
)
select p.firstname, t.shortname
from pc
inner join tc on pc.titleid = tc.titleid
inner join person p on pc.personid = p.personid
inner join title t on pc.titleid = t.titleid
where cnt_pc = cnt_tc
```

The general idea is to select how many certs for a certain title is needed, and how many certs one have for that title -- if it's a match, than we assume that one has the title as well. Counting could be done in numerous ways.

Comment: I like this one with CTE better as it is easier to follow what is going on.

Comment: Only thing is may be to replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct pc.certificationid)` etc depending if there is additional primary key on personcertification or titlecertifications tables

Comment: This one seems to be working, however what is the performance of this when there is say 500 certifications, 30 titles each requiring 4 certifications and 500 users? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Properly indexed, it will perform well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this. Here is one:

```
select p.ID, p.Name, tcount.ID
from Person p
inner join 
(
    -- Get the count of certs for each title for each person
    select pc.PersonID, t.ID TitleId, count(*) CertCount
    from PersonCertification pc
    inner join Certification c on c.ID = pc.CertificationID
    inner join TitleCertification tc on tc.CertificationId = c.ID
    inner join Title t on t.ID = tc.TitleID
    group by pc.PersonID, t.ID
) cntByTitle on cntByTitle.PerdonID = p.ID
left outer join
(
    select t.TitleID, count(*) CertCount
    from Title t
    inner join TitleCertification tc on tc.TitleId = t.ID
    group by t.ID
) tcount on tcount.TitleID = cntByTitle.TitleID and tcount.PersonID = p.ID
            and tcount.CertCount = cntByTitle.CertCount
```

Notes: the cntByTitle sub-query might need to be a left outer rather than an inner join: if a person has to Certs then I think they won't be returned by this unless you make it a left outer. I also assume all indexes are in place. If a Person has no Titles, the query will return the Person.ID and null.

You could wrap this up as a View and then just use the View in a more straight-forward query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012` you can use the `IIF` function for this.

```
SELECT IIF(TitleID = '1' AND CertificationID= '1', 1, 0) AS fullName, *
FROM   Title t
```

...? I Think :/

EDIT: the new CASE option

SELECT 'name'
CASE
WHEN TitleId = '1' AND CertificateId = '1' THEN MCSA = 1
ELSE MCSA = 0
END
FROM 'table'

Comment: pretty sure OP wants a more general approach not having to hardcode all possible certification/title ids...

Comment: Apologies, just with the example given with only a limited number of combinations of certifications I thought it might be appropriate - If there are several certifications then I am unsure.

Comment: This still does not point me to how to "match" the required certifications against the certifications a user has in a good way :/ But thank you for the answer.
Edit: Yes, this will be applied to all Microsoft-certifications and there are a number of titles that can be gained, therefore using a TitleCertifications-table.

Comment: Try using the CASE word but again, may not be suitable for large amounts of combinations of certificates. See edited answer:

Answer (score 0):

COUNT(columnName) will not count nulls.

The following query uses left join to get nulls for certificates the person does not have

```
SELECT MAX(Title.FullName)
FROM Title
     INNER JOIN TitleCertifications
         ON TitleCertifications.TitleID = TitleCertifications.TitleId
     LEFT JOIN PersonCertifications
         ON PersonCertifications.CertificationId = TitleCertifications.CertificationId
WHERE PersonCertifications.PersonId = @Person
      AND TitleCertifications.TitleId = @Title
HAVING COUNT(TitleCertifications.CertificationId) = COUNT(PersonCertifications.CertificationId)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some direction [sql fiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16879)

```
    DECLARE @Person TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR (20)
)   

DECLARE @Certification TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    CertificateName VARCHAR (20)
)

DECLARE @Title TABLE
(
    TitleId INT,
    Name VARCHAR (20)
)

DECLARE @TitleCertifications TABLE
(
    TitleId INT,
    CertificateId INT
)

DECLARE @PersonCertification TABLE
(
    PersonId INT,
    CertificateId INT
)

INSERT INTO @person VALUES (1, 'tyy'),(2,'Jon'), (3, 'James')

INSERT INTO @Certification VALUES (1, 'MSCA PreReq 1'),(2,'MSCA PreReq 2'),(3,'MSCC PreReq 1')

INSERT INTO @Title VALUES (1, 'MSCA'),(2,'MSCC')

INSERT INTO @TitleCertifications VALUES (1, 1),(1,2), (2,3)

INSERT INTO @PersonCertification VALUES (1, 1),(1,2), (2,1), (3,3)

SELECT * INTO #FlattenedTitleCerts
FROM 
(SELECT g.TitleId, g.Name, STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(CertificateId AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                              FROM @TitleCertifications v
                              WHERE v.TitleId = g.TitleId 
                              ORDER BY CertificateId
                              FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '') Combination
FROM @Title g
) t

SELECT * INTO #FlattenedPersonCerts
FROM 
(
    SELECT g.Id, g.FirstName, STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CAST(CertificateId AS varchar(10)) 
                                  FROM @PersonCertification v
                                  WHERE v.PersonId = g.id 
                                  ORDER BY CertificateId
                                  FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '') Combination
    FROM @Person g
) t


--SELECT * FROM #FlattenedTitleCerts
--SELECT * FROM #FlattenedPersonCerts

--to get title
SELECT fpc.FirstName Name, 
       ftc.Name Title
FROM #FlattenedPersonCerts fpc
LEFT JOIN #FlattenedTitleCerts ftc ON ftc.Combination = fpc.Combination

DROP TABLE #FlattenedTitleCerts
DROP TABLE #FlattenedPersonCerts
```